# Как вывести время выполнения кода?

Tags: python

Помогите установить время выполнение к этому шуточному коду что бы в последней строке выводилось время выполнения.

вот сам код:

```
a = int(input("Введите пароль а я его взломаю:"))
b = 0
c = 0
if a > 0:
 while a > 0:
  b += 1
  print(b)
 if a == b:
  break
print("Пароль взломан!")
```

Comment: Может быть вам нужен [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface)?

Comment: Да но я знаю всего несколько модулей и не умею им пользоваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time

a = int(input("Введите пароль а я его взломаю:"))
t = time.perf_counter()
b = 0
c = 0
if a > 0:
    while a > 0:
        b += 1
        print(b)
        if a == b: break
print("Пароль взломан!")

print(time.perf_counter() - t)
```

---

Либо так:

```
import timeit

code = '''
def foo(a):
    b = 0
    c = 0
    if a > 0:
        while a > 0:
            b += 1
            # print(b)
            if a == b: break
    #print("Пароль взломан!")
    return b
foo(1234)
'''

timeit.timeit(code, number=500)
```

Comment: P.S. В первом случае время считайте после ввода числа.